# Can NGINX be used to route traffic to a Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, nginx, reverse-proxy

It's unclear for me and I haven't attempted yet, but would like to know if I can have a NGINX server routing traffic to a Firebase instance. I can't find relevant articles on internet and neither here so, maybe some fo you already tried this.

**Background:**

Our React app is running on Firebase already. But, we also have a landing page/website which is backed by Webflow.io to allow quicker edits with less developer frustration. They are also running on separate domains. 
We already have an instance of NGINX(inside a docker container) as part of our API gateway so, would be good to use the same instance.

**Result:**

What we are looking to achieve, is to put both React app and landing page on the same domain. Then, use NGINX to route to required instance wether the user is logged-in or not. Anyone attempted something like this? If not this doesn't work, I'm open to general ideas on how to make it better from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do this, for example if you're using OAuth you can perform a token introspection from nginx whose result will determine the route to use, take a look at this https://www.nginx.com/blog/validating-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-nginx/

Alternatively you can use something similar to the google IAP that is probabely more easy to secure for production, i know that ory/oauthkeeper is easy to use, open source and hightly customizable.

Comment: Sure, token introspection is the solution for the second part of this issue. I'm wondering how can I also resolve the DNS. Because both Firebase and Webflow.io would like to use the same domain name but pointed to different IP addresses.

Comment: I think that you must use your DNS from nginx only and use it as a reverse-proxy to redirect traffic to your firebase / webflow IPs